# Making API fetch request with Headers API

Tags: reactjs, ajax, http, axios

I am currently learning how to make HTTP requests with headers and tokens. I am currently stuck trying to make the request straight out of my app.

I can make the request fine on POSTMAN but when I try to make the request on my app I get an Authorization Error (401)

I am currently working on this still. Here is my code, for example.

```
axios.get("https://dev.to/api/articles/me/published", {
            headers: {
                'api-key': process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY,
            },
        }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am still getting an unauthorized error, unfortunately.

I can't figure out how to send out my API call to get authorization and see my json code.
Can anyone please lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
axios.get("https://dev.to/api/articles/me/published", {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `token ${access_token}`
  }
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```